# Ibatis read Map in Pojo

Tags: java, ibatis, pojo

Edit: Easy sayed, i want to group dynamic columns into a map in a pojo.

i want to use ibatis to read a list of pojos but the pojo contains a map wich i have to read:

```
public class FundraiserSuccessData {
private String regionName;
private String fundraiserName;
// Key: Attendance ID, Value: Count
private Map<Integer, Integer> attendanceCount;
...
}
```

Currently i'll read the attendance types and put the types as a list in the parameter of ibatis query.

```
<select id="fundraiserSuccessReport.search" resultClass="controller.report.fundraiserSuccess.FundraiserSuccessData" parameterClass="controller.report.fundraiserSuccess.SearchRequest">

SELECT VALUE(MAX(r.name), 'D2D') regionName,
       MAX(fr.firstname) || ' ' || MAX(fr.lastname) AS fundraiserName,
       <iterate property="attendanceTypes" conjunction=","> MAX(attendance.$attendanceTypes[]$) $attendanceTypes[]$ </iterate>
...
JOIN (SELECT dps.person_id,
            <iterate property="attendanceTypes" conjunction=","> 
             SUM(CASE WHEN attendance_id = $attendanceTypes[].id$ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) $attendanceTypes[].name$
             </iterate>
    FROM daily_person_state dps
    GROUP BY dps.person_id) attendance
    ON fr.id = attendance.person_id
...
</select>
```

But how can i map the join to the *attendanceCount*? Cause i can't add dynamically properties to java.